# Apache redirect to same path but with a # fragment

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, httpd

I'd like to append a `#fragment` for the client to read on certain URLs (and used by an SPA).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^foo/? /foo#bar [QSA,NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

However, since `#bar` is a fragment in the URL above, it seems to get stripped out and cause a redirect loop. I've also tried escaping the hash like `RewriteRule ^foo/? /foo\#bar`.

Is there some way of limiting that `RewriteRule` to just one redirect?

- I'm writing this to an `.htaccess` file in the target directory. The webserver is `httpd -v` `Server version: Apache/2.4.39` (centos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've also tried escaping the hash like ...

The problem is not the redirect response. `/foo#bar` is being correctly sent back to the client in the `Location:` header (the `NE` flag helps here by preventing the `#` being URL-encoded in the response).

The problem is that the *browser* does not send the fragment identifier back to the server on the *redirected* request (as @Gerald stated, "[Fragments] are never transmitted to the server"). So, the *server* repeatedly sees `/foo`, hence the redirect loop. There is nothing you can do about the missing fragment identifier.

From a server perspective, you would need to change the URL in some other way, perhaps by appending a query string parameter. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^redirect
RewriteRule ^foo/? /foo?redirect=1#bar [QSA,NE,R,L]
```

The above appends a `redirect=1` URL parameter to the redirect response and the condition makes sure that this parameter is not present before making the redirect.

However, appending a URL parameter is probably not desirable.

Since this is only for use by the client in an SPA, you should instead be using the [JavaScript History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and [`replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) (or possibly [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method)) method(s) to append the `#bar` fragment identifier to the URL and trigger a client-side response. No server-side redirect is required.

Comment: Thanks. The challenge is that I have an Angular SPA within a PHP application. I'm trying to control the state of the SPA when 3rd party bots (Linkedin using Open Graph data) get the correct meta data on their first request. So JS, like manipulating the history API, doesn't work in my instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Fragments are only handled by the browser. They are never transmitted to the server.

Comment: I know they are never transmitted _to_ the server, but my hope was that I could redirect and send this data _from_ the server to the client.

Comment: Nevermind, I undersood this within the context of the other answer from `@MrWhite`.
> The problem is that the browser does not send the fragment identifier back to the server on the _redirected_ request