# How to redirect specific URL in nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I redirect a specific URL in nginx to a different URI path?

I'm looking to handle the success of a password reset to redirect to the login page of a different web application on the same subdomain.

E.g (`https://subdomain.example.com/webapp/login/login.action#/?passwordUpdate=true` -> `https://subdomain.example.com/webapp2/`).

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to hit the location block.

```
location ~/webapp/login/login.action#/?passwordUpdate=true {
    return 301 https://subdomain.example.com/webapp2/;
}
```

Comment: And it never will. The `#` and everything behind it is never sent to the server, it is only handled on the client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache redirect to same path but with a # fragment](https://serverfault.com/questions/972910/apache-redirect-to-same-path-but-with-a-fragment)

Comment: Thanks both, I didn't realise fragments weren't handled at the server side. Good to know!